# findViewById() returns null while using it in test clas?

Tags: android, testing, view, findviewbyid

I have a layout (main_layout) that i inflate in the fragment.
Now when i try to access it from test class using the following:

```
View testLayout=getActivity().findViewById(R.layout.main_layout);
```

It returns to me null?
Can anyone tell me whats the wrong thing i am doing?

Comment: @alitha post your complete code

Comment: You're looking for a view by its ID and you're giving a layout. You should have R.id.something in your function

Comment: you should mention like this.   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, container, false);

Answer (score 1):

I think you make some confusion about View and layout resource.
if you want to get layout as View,you can do it like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, null);
```

or if you want to get a view within the layout(make sure you've specified id for it. e.g. android:id="@+id/textview01"), you can do it like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview01);
```

you will get the TextView within main_layout.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try using this,

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, container, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to views by `id`, so instead of using `R.layout.main_layout` you should be using something like: `R.id.main_layout`

Answer (score 0):

First set an id to the top-level layout in your `main_layout.xml` file. For example the id could be `@+id/main_layout_wrapper`.

Then in your test class search for it using:

```
View testLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_layout_wrapper);
```

Comment: thats exactly what i did it returns null

Comment: in the code you pasted you're searching for R.LAYOUT.main_layout, but it should be R.ID.main_layout. Are you sure you're using the right one ?

Comment: Hi i tried with R.id as well but it still returns me null and yes it is the right layout.

Answer (score -1):

This type of error cause by below points:

1. Are you using same layout in setContentView().
2. You are using same widget id.

So please Check your activity properly and use debug.